# div fixed or sticky position above another div

Tags: html, css, position

I have in bottom a div with height depend on the data inside it, so I don't know exactly height bottom div.

```
<div id="BottomOfPage">I don't know exactly height this div</div>
```

the problem, I need to have another div with position sticky or fixed above id="BottomOfPage"

```
<div id="StickyOrFixed">image link</div>
<div id="BottomOfPage">i don't know exactly height this div</div>
```

I try but I still can't solve this problem, I search similar problem but I can't find it, maybe I miss it. Please help, thank you.

I try with

```
#StickyOrFixed{margin-bottom:20px;position:sticky;}
#StickyOrFixed{margin-bottom:20px;position:fixed;}
```

not work, it need top or bottom position, but I don't know exactly height id="BottomOfPage"

Answer (score 0):

i try this

```
<div id="StickyOrFixed" style="position:sticky;bottom:50px;margin-bottom:20px;">image link</div>
<div id="BottomOfPage">i don't know exactly height this div</div>
```

and it solved what i need, if div id="BottomOfPage" height 100px, sticky still above id="BottomOfPage" with margin-bottom:20px; . after scroll sticky will always 50px from bottom.

i try this take more than 2 hours, and after i submit this question, i got the answer. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:sticky;bottom:20px;" align="center">
    <div style="width:980px;" align="right">
        <div style="float:right;bottom:100px;position:relative;">image link</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="BottomOfPage">i don't know exactly height this div</div>
```

this will 20px above div id="BottomOfPage" and will scroll if 100px from bottom start from height id="BottomOfPage"
the sticky position in 980px center right